# Video texture is out of sync in blender, but fine in other programs

Tags: texturing, video

I am attempting to use video textures to animate a "scoreboard" of sorts. I've gotten the UVs correct, and everything seems to be working. Until I try to sync it up to my audio.

As far as I can tell, the issue lies with Blender turning the video into a number of frames. Both Blender (Cycles Render) and the video editing software I am using (Vegas Movie Studio 11) seem to rendering at 23.98 FPS. If I attempt to sync the video file itself up to the audio, it works just fine. However, when I set it as the file for the texture, the video seems to be a certain % too long.

For example, at frame 8 in Vegas, the video is supposed to switch from a slide of "You" to a slide of "Won't." But it in Blender, it doesn't switch until frame 11. Then, the slide is supposed to change at frame 15 but in Blender it changes at frame 21.

In fact, there seems to be a delay of x + 3 frames, x being the delay prior.

I've also tried it with different renders of the same file, with no visible change.

To recap: It is a single AVI file, it appears to work correctly everywhere but blender, where there is a strange adding delay.

I'm sure I could tweak this file to be perfect, but I'm going to have to do this a lot during the project and it seems there must be a simpler way.

Comment: check the frame rate in blender matches your video.

Comment: have you checked the offset in the image texture node?

Answer (score 1):

I would export out of vegas as a jpg sequence. then blender will use each file as an exact frame. you can then render out of blender and import into vegas matching the same frames per second.